# How to implement an assignment operator so multiple instances share common data?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, shallow-copy

I am working on C++11 application. I am implementing assignment operator.
I want that if I modify one value after the assignment both objects get modified.

Example:

```
Object o1, o2;
o1.setId("id1");
o2 = o1;
o2.setId("id2");
cout << o1.getId();  ------> this returns id2
```

How could I achieve that? any ideas

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write the assignment operator so it only does a shallow copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow multiple instances to share a common object, you might want to use a [`std::shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for its internal state:

```
struct Object
{
    Object() : _data(new std::string()) {}
    void setId(const std::string& value) { *_data = value; }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> _data;
};
```

---

Copying an `Object` do shallow-copy its internal data as asked:

```
int main()
{
    Object o1, o2;
    o1.setId("1");
    o2 = o1;
    Object o3(o1);
    o2.setId("2");

    std::cout   << "o1: " << *o1._data << "\n"
                << "o2: " << *o2._data << "\n"
                << "o3: " << *o3._data << "\n"; // Object._data set to public: for this to work
}
```

This prints:

```
2
2
2
```

Comment: You don't even need to define the copy constructor or copy operator here; it would just work. Your defined operators are equivalent to the defaults

Comment: I know about the rule of five, my point is that you define operators that replicate the default functions the compiler would generate.

Comment: A `shared_ptr`, just like a regular pointer, does a shallow copy by default as Justin said.  No need to implement any of the special member functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's late here at home, fixed; I shouldn't be on the computer.

Comment: You should remove copy and assignment, otherwise you lose move copy and move assignment.

Comment: No, remove them. There is no reason to have them. You don't have to write all that code.

Comment: @juanchopanza done

Answer (score 1):

Use a reference:

```
Object o1;
o1.setId("id1");
Object &o2 = o1;
o2.setId("id2");
cout << o1.getId(); // id2
```

A reference is effectively another name to the original object.

Comment: This is not an answer of the question

Comment: @Slava How is this not an answer? This solves the problem that the OP described, although not by the method the OP was thinking of. It's an XY problem

Comment: Code shown is to describe what OP needs and not the actual problem obviously. Your "solution" would not work for a container for example. You just provided formal answer for the code, not actual problem.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, "shallow copy" is not

> ...if I modify one value after the assignment both objects get modified.

Shallow copy of any value(pointer) is simply a copy of a value(pointer).
Shallow copy of some class object is just a memberwise copy.

Default assignment operator does the trick.

In case if you came from a C#-like land:

When you write

```
Object o1;
Object o2;
```

you have already created two indepenent objects in memory (on stack). 
And when you write

```
o2 = o1;
```

by default you do a shallow copy: just copy all data stored in a chunk of memory corresponding to o1 to the memory corresponding to o2. As simple as that. And essentially C# does the same, the only difference is that o1 and o2 are references there. So you just copy a value of one reference (not the value reference is referring to!) to another reference.

So the point is that it is all not about

> ...implementing assignment operator.

but copying references or object values itself.
In c++ writing `o1` you get the object value, not reference to the object.
Moreover, in c++ you can not copy references. But what you can is copying pointer.

```
Object* o1 = new Object;
Object* o2;
o2 = o1; // now pointing to the same object
```

But keep in mind, c++ does not have a GC, so each time you allocate memory on heap you must dealocate it later by yourself (unless you use smart pointers but that is another topic).

Comment: This does not answer the question, it only nitpick over what a shallow-copy is. If OP uses the expression _shallow copy_ in the title, they don't use it again in the question: they explicitly ask how to achieve a particular behaviour ; your answer does not tell anything regarding the desired behaviour.

Comment: What is said here is true and could be useful, but it just doesn't answer the question.

Comment: So I should just have copied your obvious answer instead of trying to approach a question in a different way... I see. Just thought if people asks "how to make assignment operator to make a shallow copy" they just don`t understand some fundamental things. So it is an answer.